# how to get data from localhost:9200 (elasticsearch) using axios in react

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the data from elasticsearch to map the cards, but after I npm start there was not cards mapped, and I think the problem about  `NCARMap: resp.data` . can you please help me?

```
//Function to create the cards with thier proipte values
function CreateCards(NCARMap) {
    return(
        <SimpleCard
        key={NCARMap.id}
        theCardId={NCARMap.id}
        cardType={NCARMap.approvetool}
        cardNum={NCARMap.num}
        cardName={NCARMap.name}
        cardDate={NCARMap.date}
        // cardCategory={NCARMap.cardCategory}
        // cardSource={NCARMap.cardSource}
        cardDesc={NCARMap.summary}
        cardURL={NCARMap.image}
        />
    );

}

//create the class
export default class OfficialDocument extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      NCARMap: [],
      NCARMapAS: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //Get NCARMap data, NCARMapAS used for filtring and sorting the cards
    axios.get('http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search')
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp)
            this.setState({
              NCARMap: resp.data, 
              NCARMapAS:resp.data
        })
        console.log(this.state.NCARMap)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by change it to:

```
NCARMap: resp.data.hits.hits,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `NCARMap: resp.data` is a problem. `console.log` was called before `axios.get` called and it's natural that you see nothing.

At `CreateCard`, `NCARMap` is treated as a Object like this `NCARMap.id`. But you gave default state as a array.

```
this.state = { 
      NCARMap: [],
      NCARMapAS: [],
    };
```

I think you have made a mistake with data type. By the way, `console.log` should be called here.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search')
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp)
            this.setState({
              NCARMap: resp.data, 
              NCARMapAS:resp.data
        }, function() {
        console.log(this.state.NCARMap)
        )
    })
```